# How to tell typescript "An object with any key except those of that other type"

Tags: typescript

I want to define a type allowing any key except those of another type:

```js
type A = { x: number, y: number }
type B = { /* Any key except those in A */ }

let foo: B = { z: 12 } // Good
let bar: B = { z: 12, y: 13 } // Bad
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```js
type B = { [key: Exclude<string, keyof A>]: any }
```

How can I define `B`?

Comment: If you tell us why you want `B` defined that way, we may be able to help you solve that underlying problem differently.

Comment: I need to define the type (B) of a variable object for GraphQL that will be merged with another object (of type A) before the query is made. I want to prevent the first one from having properties that will be overwritten by the second when they merge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following definition works: the first part says it can have any properties with any types, and the second part says that it doesn't have to have any properties in `keyof A`, but if it does have any such properties, then their types must be `never` (or `undefined`).

```js
type B = { [k: string]: any } & { [K in keyof A]?: never }
```

Your "good" code type-checks as required, and your "bad" code fails with the type error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`.

The type `{ [k: string]: any }` is very weak, but you can write a stricter type there if you wish. It may be useful to define a generic type to exclude the properties of one type from another:

```js
type ExcludeProps<S, T> = S & { [K in keyof T]?: never }
```

Note that the excluded properties can still be present with the value `undefined`, unless the [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) flag is enabled. (This flag is not included in `strict` mode, you must enable it separately.)

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUAeAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGihE10JKgF8AoUSKAIQWSgG0BrTAZ2DEAllgDmAXUwBDLCHpQAZJy4BpKKKg8IIAPYAzWBID8VCADdajBgBsIwKPt27M7RCgBemAIwAmBQD0AVAA4s4AJrb2UATSxK4cnj6+5JRQ3gDMgcGs0pFM4NAAoqgAxjY44RAACsS6YPwAPADK5AAqAHwczUoq6praeoZtJmaWxPQMUQ5Our6YJeWVNXUNjUnY+EQTdOQwXe5QXun+jHYOscTzUIsVVbX1TRvU2-R7B5zHfqk+GXRAA)

Comment: Nine out of ten times I think you can't do something in TypeScript, I'm wrong. It may even be more than that.

Comment: Strebler - The type of your properties seems to be `number`, which works just fine as well: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUAeAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGihE10JKgF8AoUSKAIQWSgG0BrTAZ2DEAllgDmAXSr4ixelABknLgGkooqDwggA9gDNYEgPxUIAN1qMGAGwjAoenTsztEKAF6YAjACZ5Aen8oAHEnABMbOygCAENiFw4Pbx9ySigvAGYAoNYYsKA)

Comment: Thanks. Why does something like `type B = Omit<{ [key: string]: any }, keyof A>` not work ?

Comment: `Omit<..., keyof A>` just creates a type which doesn't require any of the keys of `A`; it doesn't forbid them.

Comment: This does not forbid properties completely; you can still set them to `undefined`. e.g. `let bar: B = { z: 12, y: undefined };`

Comment: @MichaelTheriot That's true but rarely important, because objects don't tend to have properties of type `undefined` (that is, even if the property has the value `undefined`, its type is almost always something wider, so it wouldn't be assignable). That said, if that's a problem you can fix it by enabling the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag. I've edited to add this information.